# How many numbers from 0-4095 can be represented with 2 binary digits?

Tags: binary

How many decimal numbers 0-4095 can be converted into a binary number that has exactly 2 '1s'?

Comment: $\binom{12}{2} = 66$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that $4095=2^{12}-1$, therefore the integers in the interval $[0,4095]$ are precisely the ones that can be represented by using 12-digits binary numbers. Now among the 12 digits you have to choose 2 digits where to place the ones. In how many ways this choice can be done?